# How to follow a path with a fixed camera direction?

Tags: camera, constraints

I would like that my camera follows a path without rotating. How can I manage that?

Below I added some pictures where you can see my settings and the problem.

[image: Problem1]

[image: Problem2]

[image: Settings]

Comment: Deactivate the _Follow Curve_ option in the constraint settings.

Comment: If I do that, the camera doesn´t point in the right direction. How can I change the direction?

Comment: Rotate the camera, so that it points in the right direction?